# KSQL Group By to drop previous values and only use the LAST

Tags: ksqldb

I have a Kafka topic "events" which records user image votes and has json in the following structure:

```
{"category":"image","action":"vote","label":"amsterdam","ip":"1.1.1.1","value":2}
```

I need to receive on another topic the sum of all votes for the label (e.g. amsterdam) but drop any votes that came from the same IP address using only the last vote. This topic should have json in this format:

```
{label:”amsterdam”,SCORE:8,TOTAL:3}
```

SCORE is a sum of all votes and TOTAL is the number of votes counted.

The solution I made creates a stream from the topic events:

```
CREATE STREAM st_events
  (CATEGORY STRING, ACTION STRING, LABEL STRING, VALUE BIGINT, IP STRING)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='events', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Then, I create a table  tb_votes which calculates the score and total for each label and IP address:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_votes WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='tb_votes', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=1) AS SELECT
  st_events.LABEL "label", SUM(st_events.VALUE-1) "score", CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT) "total"
FROM st_events
WHERE
    st_events.category='image' AND st_events.action='vote'
GROUP BY st_events.label, st_events.ip
EMIT CHANGES;
```

The problem is that instead of dropping all the previous votes coming from the same ip address for the same image, Kafka uses all of them. This makes sense as it is a GROUP BY.

Any idea how to "drop" all previous votes and only use the latest values for an image/ IP?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "drop"? Since you specified this as a table it will be log-compacted based on the key (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) so eventually all that will be left in the topic is only the latest values for an image/IP. From my understanding (might be wrong) there is no way to actively force a previous record to be deleted but you could setup an aggressive compaction policy.

Comment: I am interested in keeping the LAST value for an image/IP. Does that mean all I have to do is set the key to image+IP and it will be "compacted"?

Comment: You could write a UDAF: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a two stage aggregation.

The first stage should build a table with a primary key containing both the `ip` and `label` and another column holding the `value`.

Build a second table from this first table to get the `count` and `sum` per-label that you need.

If another vote comes in from the same `ip` for the same `label` then the first table will be updated with the new `value` and the second table will be correctly updated. It will first remove the old `value` from the `count` and `sum` and then apply the new `value`.

ksqlDB does not yet support multiple primary key columns (though its coming VERY soon!).  So when you group by two columns it just does a funky string concatenation. But we can work with that for now.

```sql
CREATE TABLE BY_IP_AND_LABEL AS
  SELECT
    label + '-' + ip AS ipAndLabel,
    value
  FROM st_events
  GROUP BY ip + '@' + label;


CREATE TABLE BY_LABEL AS
 SELECT
   SUBSTRING(labelAndIp, INSTR(labelAndIp, '@')) AS label,
   SUM(VALUE-1) AS score,
   COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM BY_IP_AND_LABEL
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ipAndLabel, INSTR(ipAndLabel, '@'));
```

The first table creates a composite key with and `@` as the separator. The second table uses `INSTR` and `SUBSTRING` to find the separator and extract the `label`.

Note: I've not tested this - I could have some 'off-by-one' errors in the logic.

This should do what you need.